# Zoom participant name glitch

Tags: dependencies, zoom-meeting

I have Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. Occasionally while using Zoom (Version 5.10.3)  client, my name and profile picture will swap with another participant's name and profile picture. Then, after a short period (usually a couple seconds or a few minutes), it will revert to normal. I am not sure what is causing this glitch. After typing in `sudo apt depends zoom` it seems like I have all the dependencies installed:

```
Depends: libxcb-keysyms1
Depends: libglib2.0-0
Depends: libxcb-shape0
Depends: libxcb-shm0
Depends: libxcb-xfixes0
Depends: libxcb-randr0
Depends: libxcb-image0
Depends: libfontconfig1
Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx
Depends: libegl1-mesa
Depends: libxi6
Depends: libsm6
Depends: libxrender1
Depends: libpulse0
Depends: libxcomposite1
Depends: libxslt1.1
Depends: libsqlite3-0
Depends: libxcb-xtest0
Depends: libdbus-1-3
Depends: libxtst6
Depends: ibus
  ibus:i386
Depends: libxcb-xinerama0
Depends: libxkbcommon-x11-0
Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.6)
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: The Zoom server decides where each participant window appears. As long as your name and picture move together (you are always you, never with my picture or name), what does it matter?

Comment: @waltinator Sometimes another participant would type something in the chat with my name and profile picture swapped and people would think I typed something when I didn't. So other people are affected by it.